# Code with foreach AND coordinate does not compile - but if i remove one or the other, it compiles

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles, foreach, coordinates

Based on [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/282038/why-does-storing-a-tikzset-parameter-in-a-coordinate-cause-an-error/282042#282042) i did some experiments with `tikzset`, `coordinate`s and `foreach`. The following code plots four times the same thing. Twice with and twice without a `tikzset`. Twice with and twice without `foreach`. The variante where I use `foreach` and `coordinate` does not work. Why is that? The syntax looks ok to me...

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\tikzset{
  pics/coordiarrow/.style 2 args={
    code={
      \coordinate (A) at #1;
      \coordinate (B) at #2;
      \node [left] at (A) {#1};
      \node [left] at (B) {#2};
      \draw [->, thick] (A) -- (B);
    }}}

\tikzset{
  pics/paraarrow/.style 2 args={
    code={
      \node [left] at #1 {#1};
      \node [left] at #2 {#2};
      \draw [->, thick] #1 -- #2;
    }}}

\begin{document}

  \begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw[help lines] (-3,-3) grid (3,3);
  \pic at (0,0) {coordiarrow={(1,1)}{(3,3)}}; %%% Uses coordinates but no foreach
  \pic at (0,0) {coordiarrow={(-1,1)}{(-3,3)}};
  \pic at (0,0) {coordiarrow={(1,-1)}{(3,-3)}};

  \begin{scope}[shift={(8,0)}]
  \draw[help lines] (-3,-3) grid (3,3);
  \pic at (0,0) {paraarrow={(1,1)}{(3,3)}}; %%% Uses no coordinates and no foreach
  \pic at (0,0) {paraarrow={(-1,1)}{(-3,3)}};
  \pic at (0,0) {paraarrow={(1,-1)}{(3,-3)}};
  \end{scope}

  \begin{scope}[shift={(0,7)}]
  \draw[help lines] (-3,-3) grid (3,3);
  \foreach \from/\to in                      %%% Uses no coordinates but uses foreach
  {{(1,1)}/{(3,3)},{(-1,1)}/{(-3,3)},{(1,-1)}/{(3,-3)}}
  {\pic at (0,0) {paraarrow={\from}{\to}};}

%%%%%% If uncommented, it does not compile anymore %%%%% 
%  \begin{scope}[shift={(8,0)}]
%  \draw[help lines] (-3,-3) grid (3,3);
%  \foreach \from/\to in                     %%% Uses coordinates and foreach
%  {{(1,1)}/{(3,3)},{(-1,1)}/{(-3,3)},{(1,-1)}/{(3,-3)}}
%  {\pic at (0,0) {coordiarrow={\from}{\to}};}
%  \end{scope}
  \end{scope}

  \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Does this question help? http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34090/variables-in-tikz

Comment: Weird. Off-topic: `\to` is a bad choice since it is also a standard macro. That's not the problem, mind.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The macros Ti*k*Z used to handle `coordinate` and `node` are different since `node` is more complex than `coordinate`. According to the error message, it sounds like an expanding-order problem: when Ti*k*Z meets a `coordinate`, it wants to see `at (`. But it sees `at \to` instead and reports `doesn't match definition`-error. See `tikz.code.tex` line 3614 for more information.

> ```
> \def\tikz@@coordinate@@at[#1](#2)at#3({%
>   \def\tikz@coordinate@caller{\tikz@fig ode[shape=coordinate,#1](#2)at}%
>   \tikz@scan@one@point\tikz@@coordinate@at@math(%
> }
> ```

To solve it, on can rewrite

```
\tikzset{
  pics/coordiarrow/.style 2 args={
    code={
      \path #1 coordinate (A);
      \path #2 coordinate (B);
      \node [left] at (A) {#1};
      \node [left] at (B) {#2};
      \draw [->, thick] (A) -- (B);
    }}}
```

So that `\from` and `\to` are expanded way before Ti*k*Z reads `coordinate`.

---

Or... one might redefine `\tikz@@coordinate@@at` and see what will happen.